# fb:iframe doesn't work in Facebook app canvas?

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-iframe

I'm making a flash facebook app. I tried using fb:swf and fb:iframe but there is no swf object in canvas. I'm using Heroku.

This is my iframe code between body tags in index.php:

```
    <fb:iframe src="https://myappname.herokuapp.com/ifrm.html" width="700" height="425" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></fb:iframe>
```

When I run ifrm.html in browser, swf is working well (I embedded the swf code in ifrm.html). But in the canvas, it's not working.

Comment: FBML has been deprecated _ages_ ago. Start reading docs here on how to embed a web app into Facebook by today’s methods: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Comment: if you find a solution would you mind posting for this as i am trying to do exactly the same thing although i am completely new to facebook development i don t know if thisa post will help you or whether this is outdated aswel...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112849/how-to-embed-iframe-in-facebook?rq=1

Comment: Hi, anna. I added the SWF to the page by using HTML's **<object>** tags. You can embed the SWF between the body tags like adding a SWF to any HTML page. Also you can use swfobject's **embedSwf(...)**. (Google it for detailed info.)